# Ingress making react app not to route correctly

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a react app that works fine. However after putting it in k8s and installing ingress, whenever I refresh a page i get the following [image: error 404] although it just refreshed the page. How do I correct this?

Here is a snippet of my yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:      
      - path: /api/auth/*
        backend:
          serviceName: um-service 
          servicePort: 5001
      - path: /api/profile/*
        backend:
          serviceName: um-service 
          servicePort: 5001
      - path: /api/pass/*
        backend:
          serviceName: um-service 
          servicePort: 5001

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: admin-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /admin
        # pathType: Exact
        backend:
          serviceName: admin-service
          servicePort: 4000
```

I must say I have challenges hitting the admin backend. It just doesn't load i.

Comment: It seems it is going to default-backend. Can you provide your ingress yaml? otherwise it's difficult to point out the mistake.

Comment: I have updated my question. As mentioned, I can't access my admin backend even with rewrite annotation.

Comment: Is it pointing to correct service/pod? Is there any response when you try to `curl` service IP?